# Best way to totalise dynamically created table row and column values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I've to create a table with a row of input boxes.
The values entered in will then be multiplied by script and the answer placed in the last input box, the row total, if you will.

There is a button above the table to add another row.
Each time a row is added, the same input boxes need to appear, and the same 'row script' to calculate the row total.

Once a particular row has been added/updated, and it's row total calculated, a final number needs to be found, which is essentially the total of the row totals. Let's call it the column total.

My skills aren't super high, am learning as I go, especially from the decent responses this site seems to attract. One hopes this is at least understandable....

I've managed to get row to be added by a button using table.insertrow, and the scripts for doing the math are no problem. I have also managed to use a simple loop to create the dynamic variable names for each input box; named the same and numbered by row.

Where I'm stuck is generating the scripts to totalise a line and then another tot totalise the table, as the script needs to factor in how many rows there are, and I can't see how to write this except using Eval() (so far..).

I've also experimented a little with this and each but just got bogged down and could no longer see the logical flow.

What I've written to date is now just a mess.

Instead of posting code for comment/fix, I seek to better understand which way to address the problem using Javascript if at all possible, hopefully without using Eval().

Any suggestions would be welcomed by this brain-dead, gone bleary, wishing he hadn't started, noob.

UPDATE: Have seen a lot of ways to use JQuery, but it's not for me at the moment.

perhaps phrased differently - how in javascript would you loop through a table column, adding up all of the cell contents (numbers) in that column, please. I can't seem to figure out how to use Each as the variable names are different (numbered) per row.

Comment: Missing you code, sorry

Comment: wow - fast reply! :)   What I've written to date is now just a mess.
Instead of posting code for comment/fix, I seek to better understand which way to address the problem using Javascript if at all possible, hopefully without using Eval()

Comment: ouch, thanks also for the downvote. am new to this, and have written the question as clearly as I can, having spent almost a week researching and learning how to do the first bits myself.

Comment: perhaps phrased differently - how in javascript would you loop through a table column, adding up all of the cell contents (numbers) in that column, please. I can't seem to figure out how to use Each as the variable names are different (numbered) per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var tr = document.createElement("<tr>");
var td = document.createElement("<td>");
tr.appendChild(td);
```

You have to create table row, fill it with cells, cells with buttons and so on. As result you will have table row variable which you can insert every time your button clicked.

Comment: thank you for this. i think i'm further along though. i have the dynamic table row addition/deletion working. I've managed to get row to be added by a button using table.insertrow, and the scripts for doing the math are no problem. I have also managed to use a simple loop to create the dynamic variable names for each input box; named the same and numbered by row.
Where I'm stuck is generating the scripts to totalise a line and then another tot totalise the table, as the script needs to factor in how many rows there are, and I can't see how to write this except using Eval() (so far..).

Comment: i'm essentially stuck on referencing dynamically created (numbered) variable names, and on dynamically generating the row totalising script for each newly added row.

Comment: After all elements inserted you should be able to iterate through your table. You don't need variable names. Btw in html forms it's ok to have the same input fields names - they will be recognised as an array later.

Comment: just an example if you have a table with id test, you can access first cell value like this:


var table =  document.getElementById('test');
console.log(table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML);

Comment: Ahh, turns into an array i did not know that, thank you. Will give your method a go shortly and come back to you. Very much appreciated.

Comment: yep, now knowing that a form turns into an array and can be accessed via the DOM, i have managed to make what i needed and learn plenty more, too. Thank you so much for taking the time out, super appreciated.